# Netty - problems performing TLS handshake with an iOS device

Tags: java, ios, ssl, netty, bouncycastle

I am working on a Java alternative to [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice) (not a wrapped or binding over the native libs).

I decided it makes sense to use [Netty](https://netty.io/) (v4.1.12) as the communication layer, due to the nature of multiple protocol layers involved with communicating with services on the device, which Netty can easily handle using pipeline configurations.

After implementing a few simple queries from Usbmux and Lockdown, I am trying to perform TLS handshake to request specific services on the device.

First, I've tried the simple approach - adding an `SslHandler` to the pipeline:

```
SslContext context = SslContextBuilder.forClient().build();
channel.pipeline().addFirst(context.newHandler(channel.alloc()));
```

But it seems the certificate sent from the device is not valid, in the eyes of the JDK x509 certificate parser:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Empty issuer DN not allowed in X509Certificates
...
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: Empty issuer DN not allowed in X509Certificates
```

Next thing I tried, was using [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) as ssl handler.
`bouncycastle` successfully parsed the certificate, but failed during the handshake with a different error:

```
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsFatalAlert: illegal_parameter(47)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsClientProtocol.receiveServerHelloMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsClientProtocol.handleHandshakeMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.processHandshakeQueue(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.processRecord(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.blockForHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsClientProtocol.connect(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried to debug into `bouncycastle` and understand what was the illegal parameter, and it seems to me that there's a mismatch in the protocol version requested by the device (TLSv1.0) vs the one requested by the client (TLSv1.2).

I would paste a sample working code here, but getting to the part of the SSL session requires pretty large set of tools and parsing libraries.
I will try to create a sample `git` repo for this purpose (maybe even make the whole project open source later), but I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction in the meanwhile.

Feel free to ask for other materials, such as hex dump of the handshake, or the certificates involved.

Comment: before doing anything else please try to use a recent version of netty

Comment: Thanks. I ended up writing my own non blocking ssl handler and adding it to the pipeline. For now everything works as expected.